# Debugging "malloc error: pointer being freed was not allocated", using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, memory-management, gdb

I am trying to write an minimalist version of the standard container std::list, as a C++ exercise.  However, I'm facing difficulties with the memory management, as I am new to C++, and come from python/java, where we don't have to worry about that much.  The code is below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class List {
    public:
        typedef std::size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef const T& const_reference;

        template <typename U> class Node {
            public:
                Node() { 
                    data = NULL; 
                    init();
                }
                Node(const U val) { 
                    data = new U(val);
                    init();
                }

                void init() {
                    prev = NULL;
                    next = NULL;
                }

                ~Node() {
                    if (data != NULL)
                        delete data;
                    if (prev != NULL)
                        delete prev;
                    if (next != NULL)
                        delete next;
                }

                U* data;
                Node* prev;
                Node* next;
        };


        class iterator {
            public:
                iterator() {
                    n = new Node<T>();
                }
                iterator(const T val) {
                    n = new Node<T>(val);
                }
                iterator(Node<T>* nodeptr) {
                    n = nodeptr;
                }
                ~iterator() {
                    delete n;
                }       

                iterator operator++() {
                    n = n->next;
                }
                iterator operator--() {
                    n = n->prev;
                }
                T& operator*() {
                    return *(n->data);
                }
                bool operator==(iterator other) {
                    return (this->n == other.n);
                }   
                Node<T>* n;
        };

        List() {
            _begin = new iterator();
            _end = new iterator(begin.n);
        }

        List(size_type n, T val) {
            init(val);
        }

        ~List() {
            delete _begin;
            delete _end;
        }

        void init(T val) {
            _begin = new iterator(val);
            Node<T>* nextNode = new Node<T>();
            _begin->n->next = nextNode;
            nextNode->prev = _begin->n;
            _end = new iterator(nextNode);
        }

        void push_back(T val) {
            if(_begin == _end) {
                delete _begin;
                delete _end;
                init(val);
            }
            else {
                Node<T>* endNode = _end->n;
                Node<T>* lastNode = endNode->prev;
                Node<T>* append = new Node<T>(val);
                lastNode->next =  append;
                append->next = endNode;
                append->prev = lastNode;
                endNode->prev = append;
            }
        }

        iterator begin() {return *_begin;}
        iterator end() {return *_end;}
    private:
        iterator* _begin;
        iterator* _end;
};

int main() {
    List<int> derp= List<int>(3,3);
    List<int>::iterator i = derp.begin();
    std::cout << *i;
    derp.push_back(4);
    std::cout << *i;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
a.out(814) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbab0403a70: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
33Abort trap: 6
```

I used the GNU debugger to set the break point as intended, and got the following results:

```
(gdb) break malloc_error_break
Function "malloc_error_break" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (malloc_error_break) pending.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/samadwara/Projects/C++/a.out
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++.............................. done
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fff90721588
Pending breakpoint 1 - "malloc_error_break" resolved
a.out(835) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103a90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fff90721588 in malloc_error_break ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fff90721588 in malloc_error_break ()
#1  0x00007fff90722942 in free ()
#2  0x0000000100001864 in List<int>::Node<int>::~Node (this=0x100103a70) at list2.cpp:30
#3  0x0000000100001894 in List<int>::Node<int>::~Node (this=0x100103ad0) at list2.cpp:32
#4  0x00000001000018d0 in List<int>::Node<int>::~Node (this=0x100103a70) at list2.cpp:34
#5  0x000000010000190f in List<int>::iterator::~iterator (this=0x7fff5fbff930) at list2.cpp:55
#6  0x00000001000012ae in main () at list2.cpp:117
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000000100001864 in List<int>::Node<int>::~Node (this=0x100103a70) at list2.cpp:30
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
30                          delete data;
(gdb) l
25                      next = NULL;
26                  }
27
28                  ~Node() {
29                      if (data != NULL)
30                          delete data;
31                      if (prev != NULL)
32                          delete prev;
33                      if (next != NULL)
34                          delete next;
```

I see that the problem is with delete data, but to my understanding data is always initialized with new, so I don't see the problem.  Any suggestions, even on other aspects of the code, are appreciated.

Comment: `delete NULL` is a no-op BTW, and use `nullptr`. Also, you're not debugging your latest source.  Finally, the destructor for a node should not also deallocate its sibling nodes.  What happens when they destruct?

Comment: `I am trying to write an minimalist version of the standard container std::list, as a C++ exercise`  That's like a beginner piano student saying "I'm trying to play this minimalist version of Beethoven's piano concerto".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
            ~Node() {
                if (data != NULL)
                    delete data;
                if (prev != NULL)
                    delete prev;
                if (next != NULL)
                    delete next;
            }
```

When you delete the 1st node, it tries to delete the 2nd node by `delete next;`

However, in `~Node()` for the 2nd node, it tries to delete the 1st node *again* through `delete prev;`.

The correct way is deleting only `data` in `~Node()`; iterate through the list to delete each node instead of deleting through `prev` and `next`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but how would you suggest modifying the ~iterator method, so that I don't end up making the exact same error in a different location?

Comment: I would suggest never allocate or deallocate `Node` in `iterator()` and `~iterator()`. Let `List`'s member functions do it.

Comment: If that's the case, then what would it really mean to delete an iterator, as I do in push_back?  I thought an iterator should delete the node, because it carries the pointer to the Node?

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't I use the code the same way, and just make a node modify it's reference to itself in it's next or prev Node's before it deletes them?  So if you have NULL<->a<->b, for delete a, make it     a     NULL<->b, with a still maintaining its pointers, before deleting next and prev?  That way they won't try to delete a again?

Comment: @SamadwaraReddy with such an implementation, how could you remove a single element in list? You could only destruct the whole list.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what to do.  Thank you.